# Add checkboxes to a specific column using Javascript or jquery while displaying a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, checkbox, hover

I am displaying data in a table like this:

```
name    country    place      number
ashwin   India      delhi      123
sita     India      Ajmer      456
```

and so on.

I want to add checkboxes on hover to a column and allow the user to be able to select multiple values for that column. For instance, the user can select `delhi` and `ajmer` or just `delhi`.

Please help with some `jquery` or `javascript` code for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

HTML -

```
    <table border="1" id="demo">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>country</th>
    <th>place</th>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>check</th>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td > ashwin </td> 
    <td> India </td>
    <td> delhi </td>
    <td> 123</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" style="display:none"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td > sita </td>
    <td> India </td>
    <td> Ajmer </td>
    <td> 456</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" style="display:none"></td>
</tr>
<tr > 
    <td > sita </td>
    <td> India </td>
    <td> Ajmer </td>
    <td> 456</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" style="display:none"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demo tr").mouseover(function() {

               $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").show();

        });

         $("#demo tr").mouseout(function(){
                var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
            if (!checkbox.is(':checked')) {
               $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").hide();
            }
        });
});
```

JSFiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/Lvbj2dmm/10/

Comment: i want to apply checkboxes or select values of a specific column say for example name. and then if i select the 2 names, i want their values for further processing in the backend.<br/> another important thing is that the number of rows in the table depends on the rows returned from the database,its dynamic so how to make it dynamic.thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#one").mouseover(function(){
            $("#chk1").show();
        });

        $("#two").mouseover(function(){
            $("#chk2").show();
        });

        $("#one").mouseout(function(){
            if (document.getElementById('chk1').checked) {
           $("#chk1").show();
            }
            else{
            $("#chk1").hide();
        }
        });

        $("#two").mouseout(function(){
            if (document.getElementById('chk2').checked) {
           $("#chk2").show();
            }
            else{
            $("#chk2").hide();
        }
        });


    });
</script>
</head>


<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>country</th>
    <th>place</th>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>check</th>
</tr>
<tr id="one"> <!--put id as primary number from db -->
    <td > ashwin </td> 
    <td> India </td>
    <td> delhi </td>
    <td> 123</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" style="display:none"></td> <!--here but use tr id_chk -->
</tr>
<tr id="two"> <!--put id as primary number from db -->
    <td > sita </td>
    <td> India </td>
    <td> Ajmer </td>
    <td> 456</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" style="display:none"></td><!--here but use tr id_chk -->
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```